# The Right way to import server certificate (+ chain) in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, certificate, pfx

I'm trying to import a certificate of server which I would connect subsequently.

1. My first hurdle is what is the right way to import a certificate
   in UWP, [note: packaging a .pfx is against the store policy]
2. Once I have imported the server certificate, How do I import/obtain the certificates of the Root CA which signed the server certificate?

I'm using below code currently but I still have above questions?

```
    public async Task InsertCert()
    {
        StorageFile pfxfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ms-appx:///myfile.pfx");
        var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(pfxfile);

        string certificateData = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffer);

        string password = "";

        await CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(
                certificateData,
                password,
                ExportOption.NotExportable,
                KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent,
                InstallOptions.None,
                "Client Certificate");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code, but there's something I don't understand.

For example, you used this line code to get your '.pfx' file in local folder.

> StorageFile pfxfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ms-appx:///myfile.pfx");

The `ms-appx:///` is your app package. The `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` is your application data folder, it equals to `ms-appdata:///local/`. They're different things.

In your case, if the '.pfx' file is in local folder's root directory, you could directly use `await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myfile.pfx")` to get it.

Then, let's back to your 'import/obtain the certificates' question. I saw that you're using `CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync` to install '.pfx' certificate in the app container store. That's correct.

Once you install the certificate successfully, you could get it by calling `Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(certQuery)`.

According to the FriendlyName you specified in 'ImportPfxDataAsync' method, you could create `CertificateQuery` as `CertificateStores.FindAllAsync` method parameter.

```
Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateQuery certQuery = new Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateQuery();
certQuery.FriendlyName = "Client Certificate";    // This is the friendly name of the certificate that was just installed.
IReadOnlyList<Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate> certs = await Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(certQuery);
foreach (Certificate cert in certs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"FriendlyName: {cert.FriendlyName},Subject: {cert.Subject}, Serial Number: {CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(cert.SerialNumber))}");
}
```

Once you find the certificate, you could use it to communicate with your server.

For example,

You could use the Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient class to programmatically attach the installed Client Certificate.

```
Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter= new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.ClientCertificate = [your certificate];
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient Client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter);
await Client.GetAsync(...);
```